# What is max_trials and executions_per_trial in keras-tuner

Tags: keras

I am wondering what is the difference between `max_trials` & `executions_per_trial` in `kerastuner.tuners.bayesian.BayesianOptimization` function. Does `execution_per_trial` somehow relates to cross valdation? `max_trails` at first sounds like number of epochs to train but its not the case since there we have a another attribute for that.  I didn't get much from the original documentation found [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-tuner/blob/master/README.md)

> You should specify the model-building function, the name of the
>   objective to optimize (whether to minimize or maximize is
>   automatically inferred for built-in metrics), the total number of
>   trials (max_trials) to test, and the number of models that should be
>   built and fit for each trial (executions_per_trial).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**max_trials** represents the number of hyperparameter combinations that will be tested by the tuner, while **execution_per_trial** is the number of models that should be built and fit for each trial for robustness purposes.

For example, let's imagine you have a shallow network (one hidden layer) with the following parameter search space:

- *Number of Hidden units:* 16, 32, 48, 64
- *Choice of activation functions:* ReLu, Sigmoid, TanH

You have a total of 12 combinations (4 times 3).

Then, at this point, when you set up **max_trials** = 40, you configure the tuner to find 40 random tuples of the # Hidden units and activation functions, e.g. (16, ReLu), (32, Sigmoid), (16, TanH)... up until 40 tuples. For each tuple you will run as many executions as you also set up in **execution_per_trial** variable, given that depending on how the model runs the optimization process, final results could be very different. For each trial and execution, the tuner will fit the model with as many epochs as you configure in the script.

Comment: also important to specify.... https://github.com/keras-team/keras-tuner/issues/192